# Variable types in Eclipse AST

Tags: java, eclipse, types, abstract-syntax-tree

I am new to Eclipse AST and I was wondering is it possible to get the type of the variable during the traversal of the tree? I read somewhere that it is possible to get it by setting the setResolveBindings. However, I don't know what needs to be done in visit methods. To be concrete, I would like to get the type of the variable when processing the SimpleName visit.

Comment: Just to bump it a bit. Maybe I should simplify the question. When I encounter NumberLiteral in the AST, how should I know what is the corresponding type of the literal? Int, double, long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolveTypeBinding()` from the `Expression` class - a superclass of `SimpleName` and `NumberLiteral` - will return an `ITypeBinding`. A method such as `getName()` will get you the type.